# How to run a macro on specific range in different sheets?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro which read some data in a range and asks if I want to change it and then change any other cell which is the same in that way. it works just in one sheet how can I change it so that it searches all other sheets the same range?

I write it this way but I dont know why other data in other sheets would not change

```
Sub standardize()
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
For Each Title In Range("O1:O2000").Cells
Dim des As String
des = Title.Value
If Left(des, 1) <> "*" And Title.Value <> 0 Then
Dim MyDataObj As New DataObject
MyDataObj.SetText des
MyDataObj.PutInClipboard
newtitle = Application.InputBox(prompt:=des, Title:=" Input The description as you      like!", Type:=2)
If newtitle <> False Then
 For Each cate In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Range("O1:O2000").Cells
 If titl.Value = des Then
 titl.Value = "*" & newtitle
 End If
 Next titl
 Next cate
 End If
 End If
 Next Title
 Next ws
 End Sub
```

Comment: See **[this Microsoft documentation](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/142126)** for two different ways to iterate through worksheets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT 1: added better code

I removed your ws_loop and placed it in the middle of a new loop that loops through all of the worksheets. I also added a select at the top to switch between sheets  and a msgbox near the end.

```
Sub standardize()
Dim WS_Count As Integer
Dim I As Integer

' Set WS_Count equal to the number of worksheets in the active
' workbook.
WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

' Begin the loop.
For I = 1 To WS_Count
 ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(I).select


''''Below is your code without the ws loop

For Each Title In Range("O1:O2000").Cells
Dim des As String
des = Title.Value
If Left(des, 1) <> "*" And Title.Value <> 0 Then
Dim MyDataObj As New DataObject
MyDataObj.SetText des
MyDataObj.PutInClipboard
newtitle = Application.InputBox(prompt:=des, Title:=" Input The description as you      like!", Type:=2)
If newtitle <> False Then
For Each cate In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Range("O1:O2000").Cells
If titl.Value = des Then
titl.Value = "*" & newtitle
End If
Next titl
Next cate
End If
End If
Next Title

MsgBox ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(I).Name

Next I
End Sub
```